# What C rating for 800 mAh Li-po battery is needed to support a 2.1 A charge rate?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lipo

I have a PCBA that uses an IP5306 chip to charge the battery and it is described as a "Fully-Integrated Power Bank System-On-Chip with 2.1 A charger, 2.4 A discharger".

I need to use a 750-800 mAh Li-po battery for the application. My question is, what C rating for the 800 mAh lipo battery is needed to support the 2.1 A charge rate, to ensure the battery life isn't reduced by the high charging rate?

Comment: The battery manufacturer will tell you the max recommended charging rate. all my E-flite 280mAh Li-PO batteries charge on an E-flite 300mA charger with no problems. The C rating is for max discharging and is 30C.

Comment: The label on my 280mah batteries say max charging at 3C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The \$C_r\$ charge rate is simply the inverse of 1 hour time to full charge or discharge** (when new ?). So 1C is a 1hour and 10C is 0.1 h.

I don't know the standard value for defining this rating but I expect it is at a reduced capacity like 80% or 90% and/or a safe temperature rise when aged with higher ESR.  (citation needed)

If using 2.4A on a 750 mAh pack and expect that to charge in 0.75Ah/2.4A = 0.31 h or **3.2C rate.** So I would add margin to this estimate for better quality, but this becomes a reliability, risk, brand name, and cost tradeoff.

Of course, Lithium secondary batteries reach 70% to 90% SoC (depending on chemistry) at the max rated capacity at the CC rate then in CV mode decline in current. Cutoff is around 5% of the CC current, more or less.

Answer (score 2):

The C rating is how fast your battery can be discharged or charged.  The rating is often different for charging than discharging.

Let’s say your 750-800mAh battery is actually 800mAh to keep things easy.  Therefore 1C is 800, 2C is 1600mAh etc.

Since your charger is charging at 2.1 or 2100mAh that is ALMOST 3C or 2400.  So to be safe your battery needs to be able to be charged at 3C.

The length of time taken to charge is more complicated, since the battery will charge at 3C until it reaches full voltage and then “saturate charge” at a continuously lower and lower current until full (which is usually preset as when the current drops to 10% of the original charge current).

To calculate time it takes to charge you multiply full C charge by 1.4.  The extra 1.4 is the saturation stage.

So your battery at 800mAh/2.4amp = 20 minutes x 1.4 = 28 minutes.  Note I used 2.4 charge rate,  and I just noticed yours is actually 2.1, but you can do the math for fun.